# flutter haversine or great_circle_distance: calculate decimal numbers that represents the circule around my location

Tags: node.js, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

Does anybody know how to do in flutter a query (using plugins haversine 1.0.2 or great_circle_distance 1.0.1 or another) to filtering places nearby one lat long without recalculate all database datas when I pass my reference location anda without use API Google Maps (my places are in my database)?

In my database there are these datas:

```css
Place; Lat; Long
São Paulo; -23,6821604; -46,8754859
Belo Horizonte; -19,9027026; -44,0340902
Rio de Janeiro; -22,9138851; -43,7261690
Salvador; -12,9016148; -38,4898477
1 bilion datas more...
```

Imagine: I'm in São Paulo and I wish filter places on radius 500 Km.

I don't wish to recalculate all my base.

I would like know if is possible generate numbers (latitude and longitude) that represents the circle limit (a circle around my reference location), converted in decimals numbers, to me apply a filter. This way I believe don't be necessary recalculate all my base but simply apply the filter on my database. Are there any another solution? Am I wrong on my propose? Anybody can contribute to help me find a solution that cause minor impact on performance?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found in xxxx this great solution, but how to do it in nodejs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119240/flutter-haversine-or-great-circle-distance-calculate-decimal-numbers-that-repre

Comment: SELECT id,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-30.053831) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-51.191810) )
 + sin( radians(-30.053831) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM enderecos
HAVING distancia < 25
ORDER BY distancia ASC
LIMIT 4;